# Dividing by a subquery by a count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a query and trying to get a percentage returned for failures vs successes in the database.

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(*) FROM validation WHERE request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE AND response != 'VERIFIED') / count(*))
AS percentage
FROM (SELECT * FROM validation
WHERE request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE)
;
```

It's returning the error 'ORA-00937: not a single-group group function'. I would have thought that the subquery would be returning a single value so I would simply be able to divide it by the count(*). Aby ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over complicating the query.  You don't need any subqueries:

```
select count(case when response != 'VERIFIED' then 'X' end) / count(*) as percentage
  from validation
 where request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Still a nub to Oracle, I never thought to put a case statement in a count function. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need just 2 subquery from dual?

```
 Select 
   (SELECT count(*) FROM validation WHERE request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE AND response != 'VERIFIED')/
   (SELECT count(*) FROM validation WHERE request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE)
 from dual;
```

Comment: Hey mate, I guess you could do it this way but I feel like I shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the best way to write the query is:

```
select avg(case when response <> 'VERIFIED' then 1.0 else 0 end) as percentage
from validation v
where request_date BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 30/(24*60)) AND SYSDATE;
```

You can also write the `where` clause as:

```
where request_date between sysdate - interval '30' minute and sysdate
```